# How do you edit Lab Process Settings in a Lab Management template?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, lab-management

Everytime I try to edit the Lab Process Settings in a lab management template in Visual Studio 2013, I get the following error:

[image]

Has anyone seen this appearing? I tried creating a new build definition targeting the same template, but the error appears again.

OS: Windows 8.
VS: 2013 Update 2

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running TFS update 3 which changed the back-end of TFS to create work items for both the Test Plan and Test Suites now.  There is something odd going on in your project, it may be that you have not "enabled" the features on the project so those things are done behind the scene.

To verify this, go the TFS portal and click on the little gear in the right hand corner, then click the control panel link (up top left) and select the project you are working under and finally select Manage the project administration page and click the overview tab.  Is there an "enable features" button there?

If you go the home page of you project and click the little question mark on the top right corner and select about, what version do you have there?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the Process template to have the state "In progress" rather than "In Progress" and the default configuration is choking. If you go through your process template and make sure that the casing is correct ("In Progress") your issue should go away.

Full details and solutions: http://nakedalm.com/find-mappings-states-defined-test-suit-work-item-type/